# How to export MATLAB data to excel sheets?

Tags: excel, matlab, export

I have a data file with 9 x 1 cell array

```
fn =
  9×1 cell array
    {'speed'       }
    {'duration'         }
    {'exercise'       }
    {'gender'          }
    {'angles'}
    {'region'   }
    {'space'     }
```

When I use the code below, only one of the data is written to the first worksheet of the excel workbook. For instance, the code below will write only the gender into the first sheet.

```
data=load('subject_1.mat');    
fn=fieldnames(data) %get all variable names    
%firstdiff=data.(fn{4}); %get the first variable    
%xlswrite('hand_data_2.xlsx', firstdiff); %write it
```

If I use the following code below, it will solve the problem but I have to repeat for all the 100 subject's data as well as change excel name at each instance. Eventually, I will have 700 different excel sheets.

```
load('subject_1.mat');
csvwrite('excel_hand_file11.csv', speed)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file12.csv', duration)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file13.csv', exercise)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file14.csv', gender)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file15.csv', angles)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file16.csv', region)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file17.csv', space)
load('subject_2.mat');
csvwrite('excel_hand_file21.csv', speed)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file22.csv', duration)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file23.csv', exercise)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file24.csv', gender)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file25.csv', angles)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file26.csv', region)
csvwrite('excel_hand_file27.csv', space)
```

How to write data for a subject into the different sheets of an excel workbook?

Comment: [writetable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html#:~:text=writetable%20%28%20___%2CName%2CValue%29%20writes%20the%20table%20to%20a,headings%20in%20the%20output%20file.%20Create%20a%20table.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting data to excel in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64283014/exporting-data-to-excel-in-matlab)